# Benchmarking in scala

Tags: scala, benchmarking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java)

Let's say I have two algorithms, how do I find out which one has a higher performance?

I mean i can proof it mathematically but if I use some libraries this can get tedious. I never learned how I do correct benchmarks without math.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The quick way is to use `testing.Benchmark`: you just write something like

```
object Bench extends testing.Benchmark {
  // initialize your data here
  def run() {
    // code to benchmark here
  }
}
```

which you run with something like `scala Bench 5 1000000` (or directly from your IDE, editing the run configuration), which gives you timings for 5 sets of 1000000 repetitions of the `run()` method. You can compare timings for each set and check it has become consistent (the first set is usually slower due to JVM warm-up).

For a more rigorous approach using Caliper, a Java microbenchmarking framework, see this blog post: http://www.decodified.com/scala/2011/04/19/microbenchmarking-scala-code.

Comment: `testing.Benchmark` is now deprecated in Scala 2.10

Comment: It would be great if its documentation mentioned WHY it's deprecated or what you're supposed to use in its stead...